# Javascript debugger tip. Show a name for a value other than "Object"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebug, chromium

I want to use the following idea for a class system in Javascript.

```
var base = Object.create(
  Object.prototype,
  {
    extend: {
      value: function extend (properties) {
        var child = Object.create(this);
        for (var p in properties) {
          child[p] = properties[p];
        }
        return child;
      }
    },
    make: {
      value: function make () {
        var child = Object.create(this);
        if (child.init) child.init();
        return child;
      }
    }
});

var animal = base.extend();

var cat = animal.extend(
  {
    init: function init () {
      this.lives = 9;
    }
  }
);

var ares = cat.make();
```

But debuggers and consoles in firebug and chromium call every instance an Object. It's annoying. How can I fix this?

Comment: Well, that is because, surprise!, everything in JavaScript is an Object.  JavaScript has no concept of "class".  It only has a prototype chain which can be modified.  You can only use the "instanceof" operator to *simulate* having a class-based system.  Most implementations put the class name and the base class names etc. as prototype variables.

Comment: In case you haven't discovered it yet, Firebug should give you clickable text that will open in the DOM tab to let you explore the object properties if you call `console.log(myObject);`

Comment: Javascript may have no concept of "class" but my debuggers do. They label objects by their native constructor, it seems, which is sort of arbitrary. I thought this might be configurable.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating and extending instance -- not a *class* but You can create your own *class* as well.

```
function Cat() {
};

console.log(Cat); //output: function Cat() {...}
console.log(new Cat()); // output: Cat

console.log(Object); // output: function Object() {...}
console.log(new Object()); // output: Object
```